# Sort Excel columns independently by color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with headers. The columns and the rows will increase as data is loaded.

I am attempting to sort by color. Excel hangs, have to restart Excel.

Attempted to rerun and now it states

> object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                For i = ws.Columns("A").Column To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))
                        If .Cells.Count > 1 Then
                            .SortFields.Add(rng, xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal). _
                                SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 208)
                            .SetRange rngSort
                            .Header = xlYes
                            .MatchCase = False
                            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                            .Apply
                        End If
                    End With
                Next i
        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean specifically?

Comment: Excel attempts but just hangs,  Have to restart excel.

Comment: Attempted to rerun and now it states object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Yes, the error is because `SortFields` is not a member of a `Range` it is a member of `ListObject.Sort`

Comment: If you want to use `Range.Sort`, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort). Otherwise, you need to first transform your worksheet range into a ListObject and then you can do `ListObject.Sort.SortFields.Add` as you were originally attempting.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback,   Will see how it goes.  Used the code above fore alphabetical sort before, but updated to color and causing the issue.  Will see if I can figure out the range sort

Comment: @Toddleson `SortFields` is also a property of the `Sort` object, which can be used to Sort a Range.  No need to convert it to a `ListObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My read of the Range.Sort is that you aren't going to be able to get where you're trying to go, and Sort object with SortField is what you need with the color sorting.

Here's my slight modification of your code:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range    'Not absolutely necessary, but helpful to set a range object variable.

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                For i = ws.Columns("A").Column To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    
                    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, i), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp))  
' Above, we set the range object variable _
' so we don't have to keep retyping that code.

                    With ws.Sort    'We are applying/creating the Sort object as a property of the worksheet, not the range.
                        If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                            .SortFields.Clear  'Kill any previous sorting criteria and start fresh.
                            .SortFields.Add(Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 208) 
'There's a lot happening in the line above.  We are both adding the new SortField object _
' (as a method of SortFields object -- notice the plural!), and we're setting the SortOnValue property. _
' For clarity, I think a better way to do that is to set another object variable there _
' and break those apart, but my goal is to stay close to your existing code with minimal change.
                            .SetRange rng
                            .Header = xlYes
                            .MatchCase = False
                            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                            .Apply
                        End If
                    End With
                Next i
        End Select
    Next ws

End Sub
```

This worked for me if the intent is to sort each individual column by itself one at a time by the indicated color floating to the top (is that what you want?).

I find it helps me set more object variables and use them to shorten subsequent code in VBA, hence my "rng" object.  Hopefully that gets you where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks, a lot.  That is working now.  Appreciate it and the feedback.

Comment: Okay, please make sure you accept the answer when you're satisfied that everything I put up is working as you expect.